# Need help to land first freelancing job using python

Tags: programmer

I am a graduation student with some knowledge of Python. I know well upto the object oriented programming and have worked with Tkinter. But that was just the basics.Now, i want to land a freelancing job and i want to know that how much of **Python** shall i learn in order to do so? Also, what specific things should i learn?

Comment: Hi Ajay, welcome to Freelancing.SE! I recommend reading through the [help], including [ask]. This will help you write a high-quality question that can be properly answerable on our platform.

Comment: We can not answer this question. How much to learn depends on what the customers ask you to do. In short, the real answer is: get a client and let them tell you what they need you to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how anyone here could anticipate what level of proficiency you need to reach.

One's success is in their own hands.

- If you strive to be *good at what you do*, then you need to learn as much as you possibly can. Then *continue* learning as things develop.
- If you're goal is merely to make some cash by scrambling together some projects for uneducated clients, then you only need as much knowledge as the project requires.

Where, between the bullets, you wish to fall is you're decision.